# ResNet50 Directory Issue

Tags: python, keras, directory, transfer-learning, resnet

I am running a ResNet50 pre-trained model for classifying glaucoma and non-glaucoma images but getting an error of directory in the flow_from_directory command. I am pasting the code below. If someone can help me, it would be great.

```
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]

train_path = '/content/GlaucomaDetectionSmall.zip/Train'
valid_path = '/content/GlaucomaDetectionSmall.zip/Test'

# add preprocessing layer to the front of VGG
resnet50 = ResNet50(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# don't train existing weights
for layer in resnet50.layers:
  layer.trainable = False
  

  
  # useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('/content/GlaucomaDetectionSmall.zip/Train/*')
  

# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(resnet50.output)
# x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=resnet50.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(**train_path**,
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(**valid_path**,
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')
```

Error: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/GlaucomaDetectionSmall.zip/Train'

Comment: ...well, it's pretty hard for anyone to confirm what's on your machine. But based on the filename `GlaucomaDetectionSmall.zip`, that is a zip file, and you are trying to reference a directory inside the zip file. I think you need to _unzip_ it first, and then use the unzipped contents as the path.

Comment: @GinoMempin I tried unzipping the file as well but still, I am facing an error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible while doing the model.fit_generator. If you can help me with this it would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question then to describe the new error that you are facing. What you are now describing is a different issue than what is posted here, which is about a "Not a directory" error.